# How to set editing option to false for a particular cell of type 'Date' in jsGrid?

Tags: jsgrid

```
In script level, The code is being used to render the page which will have the **'col A' and 'Col B'** but If user clicks on 'Edit' button these two fields is still in editable mode even though editing option is set to 'false'
```

{ name: "A", type: "date", width: 60,editing: false},{ name: "B", type: "date", width: 60,editing: false}
    Please provide your comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In jsgrid, there is a callback function 
*OnItemUpdating:function()*
 you can use this to disable editing of that cell.

```
onItemUpdating: function (args) {
            if (args.item.B.getType()=="Date")) {
                args.cancel = true; 
        },
```

Hope so this will resolve you problem.